# Why can't product build find my Developer ID Installer certificate

Tags: code-signing-certificate, productbuild

I'm trying to build a distributable version of my MacOS app using productbuild.  The process used to work for me, but I transferred my files to a different computer, and now I can't complete the process.

I give the command

`productbuild --component MyApp.app /Applications --sign "Developer ID Installer" InstallMyApp.pkg`

and I get the error

`Cannot write product to "InstallMyApp.pkg". (Could not find appropriate signing identity for “Developer ID Installer”.)`

My keychain app clearly shows a certificate labeled `Developer ID Installer: Gerald Agin (7HT9GPV6X3)` with an expiration date 15 months in the future.

What am I missing?

Comment: A probable answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/21248214/1374947

Comment: That worked.  I requested a new key and it succeeded.

Comment: I'd like to award the Bounty to Raymond A.  The stack overflow documentation says I should click the bounty award icon, but I'm not finding one.  Do you need to post an answer as opposed to a comment?

Comment: It would have required me to post it as an answer ;) . Great if it helped!