# Re-install .cer Apple "Developer ID Installer" certificates from a backup

Tags: xcode, macos, certificate, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

Let's say an Apple developer program membership has expired, so new code signing certificates cannot be requested from the Apple site. Still I have a backup of:

- `developerID_application.cer`, `developerID_installer.cer` (and the expiration date is **2024**, so it is still valid)
- a `CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest` file from 2 years ago, that was created exactly at the same time than the .cer files

**How to install these certificates on a new Mac installation, such that we can  use `productsign` to sign a .pkg installer with them?**

Here is what I tried:

- Import the .cer files in the "System" Keychain, it seems successful
- Import the AppleWWDRCA.cer in the Keychain that I used at the creation time of these certificates (https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer), idem
- `productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: MyName" myinstaller.pkg myinstaller_signed.pkg`

Result:

> productsign: error: Could not find appropriate signing identity for "Developer ID Installer: MyName"

I have looked at [OS X productsign error: Could not find appropriate signing identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244756/os-x-productsign-error-could-not-find-appropriate-signing-identity) but it does not help here: I only have the 2 .cer files and the .certSigningRequest file. I don't have another Private key file. Also when I open the .certSigningRequest file, I see:

> Please specify the issuing Certificate Authority for MyName's certificate request
> Issuing CA: Let me choose
> What would you like to do?
> Create a certificate for yourself
> Create a CA
> Use your CA to create a certificate for someone else
> Request a certificate from an existing CA
> Set the default CA
> View and evaluate certificates

What to do with this previous .certSigningRequest file?

Comment: Useful linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867878/missing-private-key-in-the-distribution-certificate-on-keychain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do, if the 3 named files is all you have.

- *.cer, Is just the public key and some attributes signed by someone else (a CA).
- *.certSigningRequest, guessed from the name, is a PKCS#10 - public key and some attributes requested to be signed by someone else (a CA).

What you need is the private key.

If you have a system running or a full system image backup (to be restored) with the private keys in the keychain (*~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db*) you can export them to move to another system:

- Start XCode.
- In the Menu click `Xcode` > `Preferences`.
- Click `Accounts` (top of the window).
- Click the `gear icon` (right of the Delete button in the lower-left corner).
- Choose `Export Developer Accounts` from the pop-up menu.
- Xcode encrypts/password-protects the exported file (*.developerprofile).

Comment: Can I ask you something?